# Es posible guardar un objeto en la base de datos sin enviar uno de los registros de las columnas en SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

Estoy tratando de guardar un reporte en una base de datos, pero necesito que cuando yo envie el objeto el campo de `requested_date` no vaya en mi peticion, ¿hay alguna manera de excluirlo?

Necesito enviarlo asi ya que el formato de la fecha lo esta dando la base de datos, asi que estoy comentando la columna `request_date` en el modelo y cuando no envio el campo `requested date` sale correctamente el campo diligenciado por la base de datos. Pero necesito definir la columna para poder mostrar los datos con el request date en una tabla, y cuando la defino el valor de ese campo llega null o vacio.

Aqui esta mi codigo:

Modelo:

```
    package com.ssc.test.cb3.model;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import lombok.Data;

    /**
     * Class that models the entity report request table of the database
     * @author ssc
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "report_request")
    @Data
    public class ReportRequest {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "seq_id")
        private int id;
        // Este es el campo en cuestion 
        @Column(name = "request_date", nullable = true)
        private String requestDate;

        @Column(name = "request_userid")
        private int requestUserId;

        @Column(name = "request_email")
        private String requestEmail;

        @Column(name = "start_date")
        private String startDate;

        @Column(name = "end_date")
        private String endDate;

        @Column(name = "report_type")  
        private int reportType; // 0 === cliente, 1 === proveedor

        @Column(name = "contact_id")  // Id from the client or provider chosen
        private int contactId;

        private String rgids;

        private int status;   // 0 === active, 1 === inactive

        @Column(name = "process_start")
        private String processStart;

        @Column(name = "process_finish")
        private String processFinish;

        @Column(name = "call_filter")  // 0 === Answered calls, 1 === Not answered, 2 === both
        private int callQuery;

    }
```

Repositorio:

```
    package com.ssc.test.cb3.repository;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import com.ssc.test.cb3.model.ReportRequest;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    /**
     * Class that extends to the repository for database management queries with table 
    report_request
     * @author ssc
     */
    @Repository
    public interface ReportRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<ReportRequest, Integer> {

        @Query( 
                value = "SELECT * FROM report_request WHERE request_userid = :userId",
                nativeQuery = true)
        List<ReportRequest> findReportsById(@Param("userId") int requestUserId);

    }
```

Y ahora la capa de servicios:

```
package com.ssc.test.cb3.service;

    import com.ssc.test.cb3.repository.ReportRequestRepository;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import com.ssc.test.cb3.model.ReportRequest;

    /**
     * Class to prepare the services to be dispatched upon request. 
     * @author ssc
     */

    @Service
    public class ReportRequestService {

        @Autowired
        private ReportRequestRepository reportRequestRepository; 

        /**
         * Functionality to create a request containing a report of the chosen type of request
         * @param reportRequest receives an objet ReportRequest with the information to 
          process the specific request
         * @return the action of saving the parameter report in the database. 
         */
        public ReportRequest createReportRequest(ReportRequest reportRequest){
            return reportRequestRepository.save(reportRequest);
        }

    }
```

Controlador:

```
    package com.ssc.test.cb3.controller;

    // Quite los imports de aqui por que son muchos, pero todos estan

    /**
     * Class to handle REST services and APIs for the download Report's class
     * @author ssc
     */

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/v1/reportRequest")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    public class ReportRequestController {

        @Autowired
        private ReportRequestService reportRequestService;

 
        @PostMapping("/report")
        private ReportRequest saveReportRequest(@RequestBody ReportRequest reportRequest){
            return reportRequestService.createReportRequest(reportRequest);
        }

    }
```

Entonces quisiera saber si cuando se envia una peticion es posible declarar que no se envie el `request_date` cuando se ejecute el .save del repositorio.

Agreadezco mucho su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que estas exponiendo el objeto de la persistencia como DTO, lo mejor es que utilices un objeto que separe el objeto que el servicio utiliza para transacciona información del objeto de la persistencia.

Pero contestando a la pregunta, como Spring Boot utiliza Jackson para serializar los objetos a Json puedes utilizar la anotación:

```
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "request_date", nullable = true)
private String requestDate;
```

Comment: Hombre muchas gracias, si estoy aprendiendo acerca de como usar los DTOs con SpringBoot y si creo que es una mejor arquitectura hacer un objeto aparte que interactue con el controlador y la base de datos. Gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Descubrí que hay una propiedad en la anotacion `@column` que hace que esta no se envie directamente a la base de datos, en este caso seria la propiedad insertable:

```
@Column(name = "request_date", insertable = false, nullable = true)
private String requestDate;
```